# Managing Session's for Direct line channel web widget

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a bot which is on a web widget, i will have this bot integrated to a parent application, from which i am fetching user's employee code. I want to handle the use case in which if a user is already talking to my bot i.e already in a session , then user cannot open another window from any other system or browser and talk at the same time. I want to map user's employee code in a way that if the above scenario happens my bot informs the user that you are already in session.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Digital Assistant</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <style>
      .example {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 20px;
        width: 300px;
      }

      .example > h2 {
        font-family: 'Segoe UI';
      }

      #BotChatGoesHere {
        border: 1px solid #333;
        right: 10px;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        bottom:10px;
      }


      .wc-header {
  background-color: #107ad1;
  box-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-sizing: content-box;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 40px;
  left: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  padding: 8px 8px 0 8px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
    background-image: url(https://example.com/ess/App_Themes/HomepageBlue/images/tab_bg.jpg);
  }
.wc-header span{
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 1em blue, 0 0 0.2em darkblue;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.wc-time {
  color: #999999;
  margin-bottom: 10px; }

  .wc-message-groups {
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(0);
  outline: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 38px;
  transition: transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.5, 1); 
  background:linear-gradient(64deg,#1c627d 0,#1c637e 11%,#1b677f 20%,#196c81 27.5%,#177283 33.7%,#157986 38.8%,#138089 43.3%,#10888c 47.3%,#0e918f 51.2%,#0c9892 55.3%,#09a095 59.9%,#07a798 65.2%,#06ad9a 71.6%,#04b19b 79.3%,#03b49d 88.7%,#03b59d 100%);
  }
  .wc-message-groups.no-header {
    top: 0; }


      .wc-videocall-image{
                cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 32px;
    background: #ff60a9;
}
.userimage {
    float: right;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 8px;

    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.userimage img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;

}
.userimage img:hover{
        transform: scale(1.5);
}
.wc-message-content {
  border-radius: 5px 10px 5px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 8px;
  word-break: break-word; }
 .wc-message-from{
    color:#ddd !important; }
.wc-message-from-me {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 6px; }

.wc-message-from-me.wc-message-from {
  text-align: right; }

.wc-message-from-me .wc-message-content {
  background-color: #107ad1;background-image: linear-gradient(#8bc4f3, #107ad1);
  color: #ffffff; }

.wc-message-from-me svg.wc-message-callout path {
  fill: #107ad1; }

.wc-message-from-me svg.wc-message-callout path.point-left {
  display: none; }


  /* from bot */
.wc-message-from-bot {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 8px; }

.wc-message-from-bot .wc-message-content {
  background-color: #dcdcdc;    background-image: linear-gradient(#d0caca, #efefef);
  color: #000000; }

.wc-message-from-bot svg.wc-message-callout path {
  fill: #dcdcdc; }

.wc-message-from-bot svg.wc-message-callout path.point-right {
  display: none; }

.wc-message-from-bot svg.wc-message-callout {
  left: -6px; }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>


    <div id="BotChatGoesHere"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>

    <!-- If you do not want to use Cognitive Services library, comment out the following line -->
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/CognitiveServices.js"></script>

    <script>
      const params = BotChat.queryParams(location.search);

      const user = {
        id: params['userid'] || '5B6RnDTSIA4',
        name: params['username'] || 'You',
        usernametext:"You"
      };

      const bot = {
        id: params['botid'] || 'mts-bot',
        name: params['botname'] || 'ABC'
      };

      window.botchatDebug = params['debug'] && params['debug'] === 'true';


        const  styleOptions = {
         botAvatarImage: 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/v4sdk/media/logo_bot.svg?view=azure-bot-service-4.0',
         botAvatarInitials: 'BF',
         userAvatarImage: 'https://github.com/compulim.png?size=64',
         userAvatarInitials: 'WC'
       };

      BotChat.App({
        bot: bot,
        chatTitle:"NIIT Digital Assistant",
        locale: params['locale'],
        resize: 'detect',
        sendTyping: true,    // defaults to false. set to true to send 'typing' activities to bot (and other users) when user is typing
        speechOptions: speechOptions,
        user: user,
        styleOptions,
        directLine: {
          domain: params['webchat.botframework.com'],
          secret: params['s'],
          token: params['t'],
          webSocket: params['webSocket'] && params['webSocket'] === 'true' // defaults to true
        }
      }, document.getElementById('BotChatGoesHere'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not a built-in or easy way to do this. You're going to have to cobble together a few additional things to make this work and there isn't really a "standard" answer. However, here's a couple of ways I can think to do this:

#### Both

Both of my ideas have similar starting components:

1. Use the employee's code as their user id:

```js
window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
    {
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
            token: 'YOUR_DIRECT_LINE_TOKEN'
        }),
        userID: <theEmployeeCode>
    },
    document.getElementById('webchat')
    );
```

#### Send an Event on Each Page Load

2. [Send an event that fires on each page load](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/WELCOME_MESSAGE.md#web-chat-1)
3. In the bot, by userId, keep track of when each event was received. Something like:

```js
{
    <userId>: {
                  lastJoinEvent: <timeOfLastJoinEvent>
              }
}
```

4. In the bot, when a join event is received, check if `<userId>.lastJoinEvent` exists and if it does, you'll want to allow unique sessions after a certain amount of time (say they talked to the bot on a different day), so you'll need some logic that says `if <timeOfLastCurrentEvent> - <timeOfLastJoinEvent> > 1 hour (or something)`, don't send the "session already open" message.

#### Send Additional Data With Each Message

2. Generate a constant random id (GUID or random string of some kind) each time the page is loaded, and [send that with the activity's `ChannelData`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/b.piggy-back-on-outgoing-activities).
3. For each message the bot receives from that userId, store an object something like:

```js
{
    <userId>: {
                  lastRandomId: <generatedRandomId>
                  lastMessageTimestamp: <timeOfLastMessage>
              }
}
```

4. On each message, update the `lastRandomId` and the `lastMessageTimestamp`
5. In your bot, on each message, check that for the `userId`, the received `randomId` matches the `lastRandomId`. If it does, you can ensure that they're in the same session, so no need to send the "session already open" message.
6. If they do not match, the sessions are unique. However, you'll want to allow unique sessions after a certain amount of time (say they talked to the bot on a different day), so you'll need some logic that says `if <currentMessageTimestamp> - <lastMessageTimestamp> > 1 hour (or something)`, don't send the "session already open" message.

Now, the problem with this is that you need to make this check on every single message, which is an "expensive" check for something like this. If your bot doesn't have a lot of users and you don't scale it horizontally, you could just store this map in memory--otherwise, you'd need a more permanent storage solution. So, of the two, I'd recommend the first.

---

All that being said, I recommend against this because:

1. This can only work in clients that you can either 1) send events on load, or 2) send `channelData` with every message. So, this would work in Web Chat, but not Teams
2. This is not easy to implement
3. If you scale your bot horizontally, you can't store this in memory, which means you're making additional storage API calls fairly frequently. Not too bad for the first options, but rules out the second.

There may be other ways to do this, too, but this is all I can think of.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so well , but still i have some questions i.e My bot will also work with Teams, how can i manage session in teams with same middleware? how can i make user join with his/her employee code there? i want to write a generic code for handling session in a generic way for cross platform applications like Teams , Skype For Business and etc.

Comment: @NikhilBansal Unfortunately, I don't believe this is possible. I can't think of a way to do this at all. Regarding the same user across multiple channels, you'd likely need to either maintain a database of all of their different login id's that are sent by each channel, and tie them all to the same conversation ID.

Comment: You said in above explanation to map the conversation id with the response and send them accordingly..but i have tried communicating with my bot with 3 different users at same time, and what my bot is doing is that it is sending the last request's response to all the 3 user's. Can you please at least tell me how can i solve this , cz if the conversation id is getting overwrite by bot, then there is no point managing the id's at my end.

Comment: You said in above explanation to map the conversation id with the response, and send them accordingly, how can i do that? is there any explanation documented by Microsoft for c# There are two types of id's Conversation and Activity , As a new user joins in the previous id's are getting replaced by new one.

Comment: .I have tried communicating with my bot with 3 different users at same time, and what my bot is doing is that it is sending the last request's response to all the 3 user's. Can you please at least tell me how can i solve this , cz if the conversation id is getting overwrite by bot, then there is no point managing the id's at my end.

Comment: @NikhilBansal Do your users all share the same user IDs? If you're using Web Chat, you need to set separate user id's or the conversation-sharing will happen. Otherwise, you might be using an improper global or static variable somewhere. I would definitely try to fix this first before moving on. If you're using Web Chat, can you update your question with your .html file?

Comment: No they should not communicate with same user ID's.i have updated with .html file, please check

Comment: @NikhilBansal How sure are you that your `user` variable doesn't create the same `user` every time by using those defaults? Might help to have the bot console.log or set a breakpoint and check `activity.from`. If it isn't that, I'd likely need a link to your full bot code to really debug.

Comment: i cant share the whole code in here, is there any private handle where i can share the gist to you?

Comment: @NikhilBansal I take it that you're sure the user id's are unique? Feel free to email vDASHmicricATmicrosoftDOTcom (replace all-caps with appropriate character). If the user IDs are unique, this is very, very difficult to figure out without being able to debug all the code.

Comment: i have debugged the code, in the html file i am passing user's employee code as user id and in activity.from i am getting two different user's employee code as user id.I am mailing you my bot's .cs file in which i am writing all the logic, i will omit most of the details from the file as there are some api calls and flow details.

Comment: i have send you the mail

Comment: I have observed my bot's behavior when a new user joins in session with the bot for the conversion, and here new user means a new user id, when a new user also starts talking to the bot on different window, my middleware overwrites the existing user's id and i think this is the main reason why i am not able to hold multiple conversations with multiple users at the same time.